# Does an Canon Ef S lens goes on a Aps C sony body?

Tags: lens, canon, sony

I have few EF-S lens from my Canon 450D. And I'm planing to buy a Sony with Aps c frame. Is it compatible?

Answer (score 1):

Contemporary Sony cameras are mirrorless and have (so named) [flange distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance) of 18mm for E-mount. Canon EF-S lens have 44mm. So you have no problem to use Canon lens (EF-S) on Sony (E-mount) body with apporpriate adapter.

Comment: I am surprised that  the adapters allow the Sony cameras to control the Autofocus and aperture  of Canon lenses. Is the protocol the same or is there some kind of processor in the adapter?

Comment: @MikeSowsun, AFAIK the protocols are different so kind of translator/processor is involved. And it is not only about aperture and focus, some Canon lens intercept the moment of making photo to freeze/do image stabilization.

Comment: @MikeSowsun I think these adapters exist partly because there was a big effort to reverse-engineer them. When Sony entered the mirrorless market, they had innovative and appealing bodies...but a dearth of lenses. There were lots of pros with Canon lenses eager to try Sony bodies, creating a worthwhile market for these adapters.